# How to specify a file to heroku execute first

Tags: node.js, heroku

Im using node,js and getting this LOG from heroku, i think it is a missing file that heroku didn't find. but in the Json file i put the main file to my index.js but still not working and do not see any post about it

```
Build succeeded!
 !     This app may not specify any way to start a node process
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
```

[PACKAGE.JSON_IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMZQZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log you showed is fine.
`Procfile` is necessary when no proc is defined. The "default" for a nodejs buildpack is `npm start`.
In your `package.json` you defined under `scripts` what `start` does.

In Python projects you don't have something similar to `npm start`. So there you would have to create a `Procfile` with e.g. the content `worker: python myproject.py`

---

edit, `package.json` was added

Here is a project that is compatible with Heroku. It's on the heroku branch not master/main: https://github.com/d-zone-org/d-zone/tree/heroku

This is there `scripts` section in `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "browserify web/main.js -t brfs -g uglifyify -o web/static/bundle.js",
    "watch": "watchify web/main.js -t brfs -d -o web/static/bundle.js -v",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
```

In your picture you don't have a start script defined.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but could you give me an examble for `node.js` please,. I'm kind lost because I think i'm already have it on my `package,json` when have write ` "main": "app.js",`. **I ADD A PRINT OF MY  PACKAGE.JSON ABOVE**